# segmentation fault on recursive fft computation

Tags: c++, math, fft

I'm using the [dif](http://cnx.org/content/m12018/latest/) radix-2 algorithm to perform the fft on a complex vector.  I'm recursively splitting my input into 2-sets, the first and second half, then performing a complex add for the first half and the second half * twiddle factor.

The function finishes but I'm receiving a Segmentation fault when I try to output the resulting vector.  What's wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int n = 8;
    complex<double> *x = new complex<double>[n];

    // Test data
    x[0] = sin(M_PI/2);
    x[1] = sin(0);
    x[2] = sin(0);
    x[3] = sin(0);
    x[4] = sin(0);
    x[5] = sin(0);
    x[6] = sin(0);
    x[7] = sin(0);


    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout << x[i] << endl;
    }

    fft(x,n);

    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout << x[i] << endl;
    }

}
void fft(complex<double> *X, int N){
    if(N < 1){return;}

    double w = 2 * M_PI / (N/2);  

    for(int i = 0; i<N/2; i++){
        double ang = w * i;
        complex<double> tw(cos(ang),sin(ang));  // twiddle factor

        complex<double> first_half = X[i];
        complex<double> second_half = X[i+N/2];

        X[i] = first_half+second_half;
        X[i+N/2] = (first_half-second_half) * tw;

        cout << X[i] << " " <<X[i+N/2] << endl;;

    }
    fft(X,N-1);
    fft(X+N/2,N-1);
}
```

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector` instead of `new`. You can then, for example, use the `.at()` member function when you're worried about going out-of-bounds. In this case, you should just use a regular `complex<double> x[n];` (prefer fixed size if you can).

Comment: Someone commented about superfluous flushing. Using `endl` tells the stream to print an endline character and then flush the buffer. Typically, you don't care about flushing the buffer right away, so it's extra work over sending just a newline character `'\n'`.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea.  I love SO for all these tips on making my code more efficient.  Thanks so much, I will defiantly edit and remember as I carry on coding.

Comment: Here are some edits. I didn't fix the N-1 bug. http://pastebin.com/z18q8FDm

Comment: Thank you so much!  Your comments have been very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fft(X+N/2,N-1);
```

That's going to go out of bounds; the size of the second half of the array is only `N/2`. My Fourier theory is a bit rusty, but I think you want

```
fft(X, N/2);
fft(X+N/2, N/2);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need `N-N/2` for the latter call?

Comment: @DyP: That's the same as `N/2`; the classic FFT requires the overall size to be a power of two, so the size of each smaller transform is always even.

Comment: If N is even, then N/2 == N-N/2.